# Dynamic Styles Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, dynamic, styles

I want to add dynamic styles to wordpress using a value from a field in a custom option page

I have created a file called it dynamic_style.php and added following:

```html
<?php

    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

    $brandColor = "<?php echo get_option('blank-body-color'); ?>";
?>

body {
   background-color: <?php echo $brandColor; ?>;
}
```

it will work only if the value is css like following:

```html
$brandColor = "green";
```

but it wont work if its the value from the field which is php like following:

```html
$brandColor = "<?php echo get_option('blank-body-color'); ?>";
```

What is the best practice to add dynamic styles to wordpress from a field value with php?

Comment: what is the output of `get_option('blank-body-color');`

Comment: You can use wp_head hook to add your css

Comment: @Mahawa Priyashantha. The output is a colorpicker value which is #000000

Comment: @Aki do you have an example?